# How can I findout what's my MSSQL server collation?

Tags: sql-server, collation

Is there a SQL I can execute to find out?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The server default collation:

```
select serverproperty('collation')
```

Which is the same as

```
select databasepropertyex('master','collation')
```

Check [SERVERPROPERTY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174396.aspx) in Books Online for other information you can get about the server (instance).

Comment: This needs the following to work ( on my db ) `SELECT CONVERT(varchar,
SERVERPROPERTY('collation'))`

Comment: Works fine on SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 12):

```
SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX('AdventureWorks', 'Collation') SQLCollation;
```

Just substitute your DB name for `'AdventureWorks'`. Or use `DB_NAME`:

```
SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX(DB_NAME(), 'Collation') SQLCollation;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the official doc given by MS, hope it helps.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230914.aspx#TsqlProcedure