# Why doesn't ICU4J match UTF-8 sort order?

Tags: unicode, utf-8, icu4j

I am having a hard time understanding unicode sorting order.

When I run `Collator.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH).compare("_", "#")` under ICU4J 55.1 I get a return value of `-1` indicating that `_` comes before `#`.

However, looking at http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?utf8=dec I see that `#` (U+0023) comes before `_` (U+005F). Why is ICU4J returning a value of `-1`?

Comment: The ordering of individual characters is based on a collation table, which has little relationship to the codepoint numbers. See http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr10/#Default_Unicode_Collation_Element_Table for a start.

Comment: @MarkRansom Where would one find the collation table for US English? The unicode specification is very heavy and I couldn't find a reference to it.

Comment: If you follow the first link in that page, it leads to `allkeys.txt` which gives the default collation ordering. `_` is `005F  ; [*020B.0020.0002] # LOW LINE` while `#` is `0023  ; [*0391.0020.0002] # NUMBER SIGN`. Notice that the numbers for `_` are lower than the numbers for `#`.

Comment: @MarkRansom I believe that answers my quesdtion. Please post a formal answer and I will mark it as accepted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, UTF-8 is just an encoding. It specifies how to store the Unicode code points physically, but does not handle sorting, comparisons, etc.

Now, the page you linked to shows everything in numerical Code Point order. That is the order things would sort in if using a binary collation (in SQL Server, that would be collations with names ending in `_BIN` and `_BIN2`). But the non-binary ordering is far more complex. The rules are described here: [Unicode Collation Algorithm (UCA)](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr10/).

The base rules are found here: http://www.unicode.org/repos/cldr/tags/release-28/common/uca/allkeys_CLDR.txt

It shows:

```
005F  ; [*010A.0020.0002] # LOW LINE
...
0023  ; [*0290.0020.0002] # NUMBER SIGN
```

It is very important to keep in mind that any locale / culture can override these base rules. Hence, while the few lines noted above explain this specific circumstance, other circumstances would need to check http://www.unicode.org/repos/cldr/tags/release-28/common/collation/ to see if there are any locale-specific overrides.

Answer (score 0):

Converting Mark Ransom's comments into an answer:

- The ordering of individual characters is based on a collation table, which has little relationship to the codepoint numbers. See: http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr10/#Default_Unicode_Collation_Element_Table
- If you follow the first link on that page, it leads to [allkeys.txt](http://www.unicode.org/Public/UCA/latest/allkeys.txt) which gives the default collation ordering.
- In particular, `_` is `005F ; [*020B.0020.0002] # LOW LINE` while `#` is `0023 ; [*0391.0020.0002] # NUMBER SIGN`. Note that the collation numbers for `_` are lower than the numbers for `#`.

Comment: Mark Ransom is close but not 100% there. I will post an answer in 30 - 45 minutes...